# Simple version of argmax continuous mapping theorem

Tags: analysis, stochastic-processes

I am interested in maximizers of a random variable taking the form of an objecive function $L_T(\theta)$. In particular, I am interested in the behaviour of $\text{argmax} \ L_T(\theta)$ as $T \rightarrow \infty$. For my problem, I am able to derive the limit $L(\theta) = \lim_{T \rightarrow \infty} L_T(\theta)$ of the objective function. However, I am not sure under which conditions I can perform the needed change of limit and maximum:

\begin{equation}
\lim_{T \rightarrow \infty} \text{argmax}_{\theta} \ L_T(\theta) = \text{argmax}_{\theta} \ \lim_{T \rightarrow \infty} \ L_T(\theta) = \text{argmax}_{\theta} L(\theta)
\end{equation}

This seems like a fitting use case for the argmax continuous mapping theorem (mentioned [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2209.08793.pdf), for example), but all the sources I have been able to locate seem to consider quite general notions of empirical processes, which are indexed by metric spaces rather than finite-dimensional parameters. I believe these results can be applied, but I am not able to since they are quite unaccessible.

Do there exist more straight-forward versions of the argmax continuous mapping theorem which could be used to justify this change of limits? Examples of assumptions which I would be willing to make is that $L_T(\theta)$ is continuous in $\theta$, and that maximization takes place over a compact space $\Theta \ni \theta$.